# How to remove quotes in between using eloquent laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to remove the quotes in the sentence between using eloquent in laravel:

```
public function scopeGetOptionCommission($query, $params, $range)
{
    $query->where('column1', $params->foo);
    $query->where('column2', $params->bar);
    $query->whereRaw('? BETWEEN rangeA and rangeB', [$range]);

    return $query;
}
```

in sql I get this:

```
select 
   * 
from 
   `table1` 
where 
    `column1` = 'foo' and 
    `column2` = 'bar' and 
    '60' BETWEEN rangoi and rangof
```

but I want to get the value of range without the quotes

Comment: Does the query still work, though?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson not working, without quotes works

Comment: You could concatenate it directly: `$query->whereRaw(intval($range) . ' BETWEEN rangeA and rangeB');`. Since we cast it as an integer (in case someone tries to inject some SQL), it will still be safe.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I had found a similar solution `$query->whereRaw(DB::raw($range . ' BETWEEN rangoA and rangoB'));`, but this one that you propose is more "pretty", thanks, works

Comment: Remember that you should _only_ do this if it is an integer and you should _always_ cast it as such if you add it in the query like that.